# Azure Backup for RM VM's

Tags: azure

I am trying to setup Azure Backup (using recovery services) for RM VM's. I have one successfully working, but my other 3 servers all fail with "Backup failed with an internal error." when trying to process the snapshot.

The server that works was deployed from the Azure gallery.  The other three servers were uploaded from a base Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard install.  I installed Azure guest agent and it is version 2.7.1198.766.  I have tried registering the server while in the same NSG that the successful server is in and also outside of a NSG all together.  No luck.  When I look at the extensions installed, the server that works has Microsoft.Azure.RecoveryServices.VMSnapshot installed and the others do not.  Does anyone know how to install this extension manually?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Azure Backup is Resource Manager Mode is still in Preview and may be there is a bug with the latest VM Agent for Azure.

Can you try using an older guest agent : version 2.7.1198.735 is available here :
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=394789&clcid=0x409

This is the agent version available in the "Troubleshoot Azure virtual machine backup" official article  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/backup-azure-vms-troubleshoot/#vm-agent